# Why does JSON.stringify return empty object notation "{}" for an object that seems to have properties?

Tags: javascript, json, text-to-speech, stringify

The following example shows that `JSON.stringify()` returns the string `"{}"` for SpeechSynthesisVoice objects:

```
var voiceObject = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices()[0];
JSON.stringify(voiceObject); //returns "{}"?
```

Complete example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLux/adg4xy06/)

Why does it return `"{}"` and not something like `"{voiceURI: "Google Deutsch", name: "Google Deutsch", lang: "de-DE", localService: false, default: false}"`?

Note that the above example does not work for chrome or iOS; it is targeted for Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` includes an object's *own, enumerable* properties ([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-serializejsonobject)) that have values that aren't functions or `undefined` (as JSON doesn't have those), leaving out ones it inherits from its prototype, any that are defined as non-enumerable, and any whose value is a function reference or `undefined`.

So clearly, the object you get back from `getVoices()[0]` has no own, enumerable properties that can be represented in JSON. All of their properties must be either inherited, defined as non-enumerable, or (though it's probably not the case here) functions or `undefined`.

Comment: Or properties that are not valid JSON data types, though that's probably not relevant to the question's example.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I have updated the example to show that voice object seems to have some properties like a normal object. How can you see (using the debug view or from the console output) that these properties are inherited?

Comment: @MathiasS: When `.hasOwnProperty()` returns false

Comment: @MathiasS: It depends on the debugger you're using how inherited properties are displayed. Frequently they're shown as being on a propety on the object called `__proto__` or just `proto`. As slebetman says, in code you can tell by using `voiceObject.hasOwnProperty("voiceURI")` and such. If it's true, it's an "own" property; if not, it's inherited.

Answer (score 6):

The answer of T.J Crowder works for me, i was creating my object like this:

```
Object.defineProperties(completeObj, {
    [attributeName]: {
        value: finalValue
    }
});
```

I changed for this and the problem was solved:

```
Object.defineProperties(completeObj, {
    [attributeName]: {
        value: finalValue,
        enumerable: true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this by doing:

```
var voiceObject = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices()[0];
var newvoiceObject = $.extend(newvoiceObject,voiceObject);
JSON.stringify(newvoiceObject); //returns correct JSON string
```

...but keep in mind the object type will change, if you require that the object is of a specific type.