# JSON.stringify print all objects in an array as [{},{},{}]

Tags: json, google-apps-script, logging, stringify

When I run this code, I get the following output:

```js
var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
Logger.log("triggers =" + JSON.stringify(triggers));
for (var j = 0; j < triggers.length; j++) {
  Logger.log("trigger +"[i]+" =" + JSON.stringify(triggers[i]));
}
};
```

Output:

```
5:55:16 PM  Info    triggers =[{}, {}, {}]
5:55:16 PM  Info    t ={}
```

I know there are a few not empty objects, why aren't they shown as a string?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I know there are a few not empty objects, why aren't they shown as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value from `ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()` is an [array of Trigger objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getprojecttriggers) - and these objects do not appear to have a `toJSON` method or values which can be stringified.

See this question [Why does JSON.stringify return empty object notation “{}” for an object that seems to have properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38542265/why-does-json-stringify-return-empty-object-notation-for-an-object-that-see) for more background.

I assume you have an array of three trigger objects, judging by your output `[{}, {}, {}]`.

You can iterate over your array to access its properties - for example, as follows:

```js
var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
  Logger.log( triggers[i].getEventType() );
}
```

Assuming you have 1 time-based trigger and 1 calendar event trigger attached to your script, you will see the following output:

```
3:54:07 PM  Info    CLOCK
3:54:07 PM  Info    ON_EVENT_UPDATED
```

A more compact way to iterate is:

```js
var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
triggers.forEach(trigger => Logger.log( trigger.getEventType() ));
```

See the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger) for more details on what properties you can access for each trigger.